# Kubernetes - Confluent Kafka Control Center Ingress Routing

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress, confluent-platform, confluent-control-center

I am fairly new to kubernetes and ingress. I have followed these steps and and was able to generate kafka cluster on my machine.

https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kubernetes-examples/tree/master/quickstart-deploy

I can port forward and see my brokers and etc.

However, I would like to create a routing to access to control center through ingress, which I am failing to do.
This is my ingress config file for the namespace:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-srv
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: acme.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /confluent-control-center
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: controlcenter-bootstrap-lb
                port:
                  number: 80
```

This is my cluster:
[Cluster Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXSxM.png)

This is the error I am getting:
[Error Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QGyE.png)

I understand dist files are unreachable, but I do not understand the depth of it.
Could someone help me to resolve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Your controlcenter-bootstrap-lb is pending state. You should target port 9021 of the other service

Comment: apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-srv
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: acme.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /confluent-control-center
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: controlcenter-0-internal
                port:
                  number: 9021
        @onecricketeer getting the same error

Comment: I dont use this operator. Perhaps you can contact Confluent Support directly, since you'll eventually need an enterprise license to use it (or Control Center), anyway. Otherwise, there are other UI projects for accessing Kafka that are fully open source, and have their own Helm Charts

Comment: I see, well I'll take a look at them too. Thanks!